# Directory NN is in the user profile, but is not listed in the RemoveFile table

Tags: wix

When I am trying to create the installer i am getting the following error:

The directory **`ProgramMenuDir`** is in the user profile but is not listed in the **`RemoveFile`** table.

How do I resolve this issue? Below is the directory structure I am using:

```
<Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
  <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="E">
    <Directory Id="Monarch" Name="Monarch">
      <Component Id="Monarch" Guid="*">                       
        <RemoveFolder Id='Monarch' On='uninstall' />
        <RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
        <RegistryValue Root='HKCU' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' 
                                   Type='string' Value='' KeyPath='yes' />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: How about I want to have Monarch subfolder deleted on uninstall, but I don't want its parent folder ProgramMenuDir to be deleted? Perhaps, that parent folder is the company name folder and has many other products of the same company created subfolders under it.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As far as I can see, the problem is in the usage of `<RemoveFolder/>` element. If the 'Directory' attribute is omitted, it takes the directory of the parent component. In your case, it is a directory with Id="EFIMonarch". This explains why you get the warning for the outer directory (ProgramMenuDir), but don't get it for EFIMonarch directory.

Try replacing:

```
<RemoveFolder Id='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
```

with

```
<RemoveFolder Id='RemoveProgramMenuDir' Directory='ProgramMenuDir' On='uninstall' />
```

Also, it is a good idea to be explicit for every RemoveFolder element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In my case I was seeing this error because I had forgotten to add the component as a feature.

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow same for me.

Comment: Would be nice to have that property in the tutorial, I think most could figure it out intuitively if it was. This is the only article I could find that bothered to explain why instead of just providing a non-working example.

Comment: [Wix's tutorial](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/files_and_registry/create_start_menu_shortcut.html) does an amazing job at obfuscating the function of these attributes. Re-using the same `Id` for completely different elements, making it seem as if they're references rather than unrelated identifiers.

Comment: Many thanks for this. After much head scratching and confusion over two ICE64 errors, your answer came to the rescue!

Comment: I had this same error and Google brought me here. However in my case, I was missing a `<ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />` under the Feature tag. Wix is obscure af.

Answer (score 3):

If other answers are still not working for you, try to check `Suppress ICE validation` option, Visual studio will ignore these validations, just follow this route:

`YourProject` -> `Properties` -> `Tool Settings`

[image: ICE validation]

Comment: what does this do?

Answer (score 1):

Just writing this up for some others who may still experience this problem even after following the answer for this question.

I had the same problem, and even after explicitly specifying the Directory in the RemoveFolder did not help me, I tried to put this DirectoryRef containing the shortcut install/uninstall somponents right after the TARGETDIR within the same fragment and it helped fix my issue.

Answer (score -6):

If following answer still still not working. Try to reboot your visual studio.