# wix The directory is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have the following configuration to delete and copy a file from WIX.

```
 <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
 <Directory Id="AppDataFolder" Name="AppDataFolder">
    <Directory Id="GleasonAppData" Name="Gleason" >
    <Directory Id="GleasonStudioAppData" Name="GleasonStudio">
    <Directory Id="DatabaseAppData" Name ="Database">
    <Directory Id="UserSandboxesAppData" Name="UserSandboxes" />

</Directory>
</Directory>
</Directory>
</Directory>

</Directory>

<DirectoryRef Id="UserSandboxesAppData">
<Component Id="comp_deleteBackup" Guid="*">
        <RemoveFile Id="RemoveBackup" Directory="UserSandboxesAppData" 
                                Name="DevelopmentBackUp.FDB" On="install" />  
        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Gleason\Database\RemoveBackup">
            <RegistryValue Value="Removed" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>

    </Component>
    <Component Id="comp_createBackup" Guid="*">
        <CopyFile Id="DBBackup" 
              DestinationDirectory="UserSandboxesAppData" 
              DestinationName="DevelopmentBackUp.FDB" 
              SourceDirectory="UserSandboxesAppData" 
              SourceName="Development.FDB" />

        <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Gleason\Database\CopyBackup">
            <RegistryValue Value="Copied" Type="string" KeyPath="yes" />
        </RegistryKey>    
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

I get 4 errors related to ICE64--The directory 'xxx' is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.
xxx={UserSandboxesAppData, DatabaseAppData, GleasonStudioAppData, GleasonAppData}
Someone else had a very similar problem here: [Directory xx is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290576/directory-xx-is-in-the-user-profile-but-is-not-listed-in-the-removefile-table). But that solution did not help me.

What do I need to change?

Thank You,
Venkat Rao

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll want to add some `RemoveFolder` elements under your components to keep ICE64 happy.

```
<RemoveFolder Id="RemoveThisFolder" On="uninstall" />
```

For more details about removing per-user data and managing to pass all the ICE validation tests, check out [How to create an uninstall shortcut (and pass all the ICE validation)](https://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2007/4/27/how-to-create-an-uninstall-shortcut-and-pass-all-the/) by Rob Mensching.

Comment: I don't wan't to remove any folders, I just want to delete one file. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You'll have your RemoveFile on install, and RemoveFolder on uninstall to keep ICE64 happy.

Comment: Where do you put this RemoveFolder??