# remove file ICE64 writing to localAppData

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="AppInstaller" Language="1033" Version="0.0.0.1"
           Manufacturer="my Corporation" UpgradeCode="PUT-GUID-HERE">
   <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="Newer version already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

    <!--icon for Add/Remove Programs-->
    <Icon Id="app.ico" SourceFile="..\Import\app.ico" />
    <Property Id="ARPPRODUCTICON" Value="app.ico" />


    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="AppInstaller" Level="1" 
             Description="The complete installation" Display="expand" 
             ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <ComponentRef Id="ProgramMenuDir" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ExportReleaseComponentGroup" />
      <ComponentRef Id="SimulatorConfig" />
    </Feature>

    <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
    <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIInfoIco" Value="..\Import\app.ico" />
    <WixVariable Id="WixUIExclamationIco" Value="..\Import\app.ico" />
  </Product>

  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
        <Directory Id="IntelDir" Name="Intel">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="app v0.0.0.1">
            <Directory Id="BIN" Name="bin"/>
          </Directory>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder" Name="Programs">
       <Directory Id="ProgramMenuDir" Name="app v0.0.0.1">
         <Component Id="ProgramMenuDir" Guid="*">
          <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuDir" On="uninstall" />
          <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"
                         Type="string" Value="app" KeyPath="yes" />
         </Component>
       </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop" />
      <Directory Id="LocalAppDataFolder">
        <Directory Id="app" Name="appV">
        </Directory>
      </Directory>

    </Directory>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Directory Id="bin" Name="bin">
        <Directory Id="Release" Name="Release" />
      </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>

  <Fragment>
   <DirectoryRef Id="app">
     <Directory Id="SimulatorConfig" Name="Config">
       <Component Id="SimulatorConfig" Guid="*">
        <RemoveFolder Id="SimulatorConfig" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]"
                       Type="string" Value="Simulator" KeyPath="yes" />
        <File Source="Gili.txt"/>
       </Component>
     </Directory>
    </DirectoryRef>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

**here is the problem and the error**

Error   93  ICE64: The directory app is in the user profile but is not listed in the 
RemoveFile table.   C:\Tools\Tools\appv\Main\appInstaller\Product.wxs   45  1   appInstaller

i read some answers and i know the problem is either with the registry entry or in the remove folder option can you please help ?

i'm working on wix 3.8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you will find an answer here: [wix The directory is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627861/wix-the-directory-is-in-the-user-profile-but-is-not-listed-in-the-removefile-tab)

On the other hand my preferred approach for userprofile files is to have your application create them or copy them from read-only copies in your application's %ProgramFiles% folder. Here is a discussion: http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21552.

Here is a recommended read on the issue of using self-repair for the deployment of userprofile files. It is a worse idea to depend upon for every year as new obstacles are added with each version of Windows: http://forum.installsite.net/index.php?showtopic=21586

Comment: so you mean i just have to add <removeFolder> to every directory in the hierarchy ?

Comment: can you assist a little more?