# Directory xx is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table

Tags: winforms

When iam trying to create the installer i am getting the following error:
Error Message:

ICE64: The directory ProgramMenuServersFolder is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table. C:\Documents and Settings\admin\Desktop\SetupProject1\SetupProject1\Product.wxs 74  1   SetupProject1.

How to Proceed further?

```
<!--Start C2 by Me, ProgramMenuFolder is used to add shortcut on start menu -->
      <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
        <Directory Id="ProgramMenuLightRidgeFolder" Name="LightRidge Resources">

          <Directory Id="ProgramMenuAdminFolder" Name="Admin"/>
          <Directory Id="ProgramMenuServersFolder" Name="Servers">


              <!--<Directory Id="ServersHisSubFolder" Name="Historian Server" />
            <Directory Id="ServersMsgSubFolder" Name="Messaging Server" />-->
              <Directory Id="ProgramMenuServersHisSubFolder" Name="Historian Server" />
              <Directory Id="ProgramMenuServersMsgSubFolder" Name="Messaging Server" />

          </Directory>


          <Directory Id="ProgramMenuUtilitiesFolder" Name="Utilities"/>
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
      <!--End C2 by Me -->

      <Directory Id="DesktopFolder" Name="Desktop">
        <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="{484EA493-A1E0-41d2-8E5D-67D30D8F03AD}">
          <RegistryKey Root="HKCU" Key="Software\LightRidge Resources\PE-Advisor">
            <RegistryValue Name="DesktopShortcutPe-Advisor" Value="1" Type="integer" KeyPath="yes"  Action="write"/>
          </RegistryKey>
          <Shortcut Id="DesktopShortcut" Directory="DesktopFolder" Name="PE-Advisor" ShortName="PEAdv" Target="[PEADVISOR]Symcon.LightRidge.PEAdvisor.exe" Icon="GRAPH03.ICO"/>
        </Component>
      </Directory>


    </Directory>
    <!-- close tag of main directory-->

    <UIRef Id="UserInterface"/>


    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
      <!-- <ComponentRef Id="WFTest.exe" /> -->
      <ComponentRef Id="ProductMain"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationHelpShortcut"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="UtilitiesApplicationShortcut"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="DesktopShortcut" />
      <ComponentRef Id="UTILITIES" />
      <ComponentRef Id="HISTORIAN" />
      <ComponentRef Id="ADMIN" />
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="PEAdvisorFiles"/>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Historian"/>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ConfigFiles"/>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="Help"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="AdminApplicationShortcut"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="HistorianApplicationShortcut"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="MESSAGING"/>
      <ComponentRef Id="MessagingApplicationShortcut"/>
      <!--<ComponentRef Id="ServerApplicationShortCut"/>-->

    </Feature>


    <!-- Start C3 Me, Component Group of 'config' files -->
    <ComponentGroup Id="ConfigFiles" Directory="CONFIG">

      <Component Id="ColorSchemes" Guid="*">
        <File Id="ColorSchemes" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\ColorSchemes.xml" Name="ColorSchemes.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>


      <Component Id="config" Guid="*">
        <File Id="config" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\config.xml" Name="config.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="HelpConfig" Guid="*">
        <File Id="HelpConfig" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\HelpConfig.xml" Name="HelpConfig.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="PIConfig" Guid="*">
        <File Id="PIConfig" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\PIConfig.xml" Name="PIConfig.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="ReportServerConfig" Guid="*">
        <File Id="ReportServerConfig" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\ReportServerConfig.xml" Name="ReportServerConfig.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="OptionsConfig" Guid="*">
        <File Id="OptionsConfig" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\options.xml" Name="Options.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
      <Component Id="version" Guid="*">
        <File Id="version" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\ExternalLib\config\version.xml" Name="version.xml" Vital="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>




    <DirectoryRef Id ="ProgramMenuServersHisSubFolder">
      <Component Id="HistorianApplicationShortcut" Guid="{484EA493-A1E0-41d2-8E5D-87D30D8F03AD}">
        <Condition>HISTORIAN</Condition>
        <Shortcut Id="HistorianStartMenuShortcut" Name="Historian Server"
           Description="Historian Server"
            Target="[HISTORIANSERVER]HistorianServer.exe"
            WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Icon="GRAPH03.ICO"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersHisSubFolder" On="uninstall"/>

        <!--<RemoveFolder Id='RemoveProgramMenuServersFolder' Directory='ProgramMenuFolder' On='uninstall'/>-->
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersFolder" On="uninstall" />-->
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersFolder" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersHisSubFolder" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="Servers" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\LightRidge Resources\PE-Advisor" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>


      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>



    <ComponentGroup Id="Messaging" Directory="MESSAGINGSERVER">
      <Component Id="MESSAGING" Guid="{980EA493-A1E6-41d2-8E5D-87D30D8F03AD}">
        <Condition>MESSAGING</Condition>
        <File Id="Server" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\MessagingSystem\ExternalLib\Server.exe" Name="Server.exe" Vital="yes"/>
        <File Id="ServerConfig.xml" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\MessagingSystem\ExternalLib\ServerConfig.xml" Name="ServerConfig.xml" Vital="yes"/>
        <File Id="ServerComponentMessaging" Source="D:\PE-Advisor Source code 4-26 11-July-2012 (Dowloaded from FTP site on19-Oct-12)\08 DesktopApplication\MessagingSystem\ExternalLib\ServerComponent.dll" Name="ServerComponent.dll" Vital="yes"/>
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersMsgSubFolder" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <!--<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\LightRidge Resources\PE-Advisor" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>-->
      </Component>
    </ComponentGroup>

    <DirectoryRef Id ="ProgramMenuServersMsgSubFolder">
      <Component Id="MessagingApplicationShortcut" Guid="{980EA493-A8E6-41d2-8E5D-67D30D8F03AD}">
        <Condition>MESSAGING</Condition>
        <Shortcut Id="MessagingStartMenuShortcut" Name="Messaging Server"
           Description="Messaging Server"
            Target="[MESSAGINGSERVER]Server.exe"
            WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Icon="GRAPH03.ICO"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersMsgSubFolder" On="uninstall"/>
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="ProgramMenuServersFolder" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <!--<RemoveFolder Id="Servers" On="uninstall"/>-->
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\LightRidge Resources\PE-Advisor" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see another question with a solution to this: [Directory xx is in the user profile but is not listed in the RemoveFile table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3290576/directory-xx-is-in-the-user-profile-but-is-not-listed-in-the-removefile-table)

Regards

Liam